# Difference between programming languages on operator priority?

Tags: c#, php, javascript

There is this line:

```
$var = true ? '1' : false ? '2' : '3';
```

in PHP, `$var` will be '2' after this line.

but in some other languages (specifically C based languages) the result variable will be '1';

It seems that PHP interprets the line like this:

```
$var = (true ? '1' : false) ? '2' : '3';
```

but other languages do it like this:

```
string var = true ? '1' : (false ? '2' : '3');
```

Im actually confused about operator priorities.

Any Ideas would help.

Comment: Only PHP has that weird associativity regarding ternary operator.

Comment: I like your observation, but not sure on your confusion. Isn't it easy to answer that different language have different way of interpreting and hence they produce different results...

Comment: Is this considered a bug? or such differences are usual?

Comment: use no more than two operations per line (function + assignment, operator + assignment, etc), and your code will be easy to read and never run into such petty issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding the ternary operator `?:` alone, the associativity of `?:` in PHP is different from the rest of the languages which offers the same construct. `?:` is *left* associative in PHP, and *right* associative in other languages. This behavior is due to bad design, and it will not be fixed according to [this bug report](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=61915).

Reference:

- [?: - Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F%3a#PHP)

Answer (score 1):

This is due to difference in associativity ,means how a expression is parsed in that language,

there are two important link that can tell u\you about operator precedence and their associativity , if you do not specify by using braces.

php manual :http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php

other http://www.tuxradar.com/practicalphp/3/12/7
[image]
http://www.programiz.com/c-programming/precedence-associativity-operators

and there is a good article about language behavior
on http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Introduction_to_Programming_Languages/Precedence_and_Associativity